# DynamoDB replication using Stream + Lambda

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, replication

I am trying to set up DynamoDB table replication using Stream + Lambda.
I was wondering how I should handle the failures.
For example, I have table A and table B and I'd like to copy any update from table A to table B.

I can set up a trigger using Stream + Lambda.
Writing the lambda function to get the events from table A and write to table B is quite straight forward.

However, I am not sure how I should handle the failures.
In the lambda function, what should I do if write to table B failed for some reason? I can do retries but what should I do if all retries failed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use global tables (refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GlobalTables.html) for multi-region, multi-master replication. Everything is taken care by the DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

you can add new field to table B ('version'). 'version' field will be the time the record added.

in case of failure updating table B, you can save the failed event to some MySql table or RDS.

you should hold a process that query the backup table, and in case the backup event 'version' field is greater than the 'version' event on table B, then update the record.

You can also use the build in aws functionality '[cross region dynamodb replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.CrossRegionRepl.html)'

Comment: Thanks for pointers. I looked cross region dynamodb replication and it doesn't explain how to resolve the failures .. is that "cross region dynamodb replication" guarantees data consistency?

Comment: it is resolving failures for you

Comment: would  'cross region dynamodb replication' still work if I need to do bi-directional sync? e.g) write to table A copied to table B and write to table B copied to table A. It's not possible that a record is updated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

With DynamoDB streams + Lambda, you get retries for free until the stream data expires, which is 24 hours for DynamoDB streams. If your lambda fails, for whatever reason, it'll retry processing the failed batch with the next invoke. See the last paragraph of this article for more details. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html. So you don't need to implement retries in your lambda code.

Just set your stream batch size to a decently large number, say 100, to allow the batch to include new updates and previously failed updates if any.

I wouldn't expect the lambda to fail very often. Even if they do, the retry mechanism you get for free should take care of it. so I wouldn't bother implementing a fix for it. I would instead monitor the lambda and trigger an alert if the lambda keeps failing without a successful execution for say 15 or 20 minutes.